# appending object to list of another object

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I seem to be having trouble appending object to a list of a different object.
ill do my best to explain:

I'm new to python and i'm trying to learn about classes and objects so i prepared myself a small exe

I have 3 objects in my program: Investor, House & Market

in the Market class all I have is a list of houses

I have a list of 3 investors each of them has a field that is a list of houses (starts empty on first **init**)

now, what i'm trying to do is to display the list of houses on the Market (which i've done)
the user enters the index of the house he want to buy and the program adds the house to his list of houses and deletes it from the list of houses in the market.

***now my problem seem to be that every time i select a house it adds it to ALL 3 investors and not to a specific one and I can't figure out why*** (probably cuz it's a ref type, but i don't know how to overcome it :/)

code:

```
class Investor:
    def __init__(self, name, budget, houses):
        self.name = name
        self.budget = budget
        self.houses = houses

    def BuyHouse(self, market, houseIndex):
        self.budget -= market.availableHouses(houseIndex).price
        self.houses.append(market.availableHouses[houseIndex])  ## i believe this to be the problem. 
        print(f'Budget left: {self.budget}$')    

    def PrintAllInfo(self): # prints all info for houses.
        counter = 1
        for h in self.houses:
            print(f'{counter}) The House is in: {h.location}\n   The House price is: {h.price}$\n   The House size is: {h.size} sqft')
            counter += 1

class House:
    def __init__(self, location, price, length, width):
        self.location = location
        self.price = price
        self.width = width
        self.length = length

    def PrintThisHouse(self):
        print(f'{self.location}, Price - {self.price}$')

class Market:
    def __init__(self, availableHouses):
        self.availableHouses = availableHouses

    def PrintAllHouses(self):
        print('\nALL ABAILABLE PROPERTIES:\n--------------------------')
        counter = 1
        for h in self.availableHouses:
            print(str(counter) + ' - ', end='')
            counter += 1
            h.PrintThisHouse()

# main #
invHouses = []
investors = [ Investor('Bot1', 100000000, invHouses),
              Investor('Bot2', 100000000, invHouses),
              Investor('Bot3', 100000000, invHouses) ]
# init Houses:
houses = [ House("LA, California",450000,20,10),
           House("IL, Tel Aviv",1000000,5,5),
           House("Rus, Moscow",40000,20,10),
           House("Switz, Zr",125000,7,9),
           House("Fr, Paris",225000,15,4),
           House("Eg, Cairo",75000,15,15),
           House("Pt, Lisbon",100000,10,10),
           House("Ge, Batumi",75000,14,6),
           House("In, New Delhi",50000,20,20),
           House("Ca, Montreal",500000,30,35),
           House("Cambodia, Phnom Pen",15000,9,9),
           House("Uk, London",1000000,10,10) ]

#init Market:
mrkt = Market(houses)


# runs 3 times 1 time for each investor to buy one house.
for inv in investors: # run for all investors
    mrkt.PrintAllHouses() # a func that prints all the houses that are on the market
    selectHouse = (int(input('Enter the house you want to buy: ')) - 1)
    inv.BuyHouse(mrkt, selectHouse)


#after each investor bought a house i want to print for each investor his house(s) in the list
# problem is that now it prints all 3 houses for each one and i dont know why :(
for inv in investors:
    print(f'\nProperties of {inv.name}:')
    inv.PrintAllInfo()
    print('\n**************************')
```

Your help will be much appreciated, thank's y'all

Comment: In the future it will help to provide a [mre]. I bet you could reproduce the same problem in a quarter as much code.

Answer (score 3):

```
invHouses = []
investors = [ Investor('Bot1', 100000000, invHouses),
              Investor('Bot2', 100000000, invHouses),
              Investor('Bot3', 100000000, invHouses) ]
```

You have one list object created by `invHouses`. And you are passing that same object to all the investors. So if you add a house to that list via one investor, all other investors also get that house in their list (cause it's the same list).

```
investors = [ Investor('Bot1', 100000000, []),
              Investor('Bot2', 100000000, []),
              Investor('Bot3', 100000000, []) ]
```

Pass a different object to each investor instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are passing the same list invHouses to all investors. Try intializing self.houses as an empty list in the init of investor